# MutableArray not storing information permanently

Tags: iphone, ios, methods, nsmutablearray

The `flickPhotosSearch` should do what the commented self. Images line does. If I uncomment, it it works fine but since I need it to work dynamically I need to get the flickrPhotoSearch to do the same thing. It is saving the same information into the images array but when it leaves the method then it no longer works.

```
[self flickrPhotosSearch:url];
/*    self.images = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                          [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"http://farm6.staticflickr.com/5095/5426345292_40ec29d5ea.jpg", @"http://farm6.staticflickr.com/5095/5426345292_40ec29d5ea_s.jpg", nil], nil]; */


       NSLog(@"%@", self.images);

   }
   return self;
}

-(void)flickrPhotosSearch:(NSURL *) url {

    NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
    AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {

        NSDictionary *photos = [JSON objectForKey:@"photos"];
        self.picturesOfLocations = [photos objectForKey:@"photo"];


        for (NSDictionary * photo in self.picturesOfLocations ){



            NSString* flickrfarmID = [photo  objectForKey:@"farm"];
            NSString* flickrServer = [photo  objectForKey:@"server"];
            NSString* flickrID = [photo  objectForKey:@"id"];
            NSString* flickrSecret = [photo  objectForKey:@"secret"];

            NSString *stringURLOriginalImage = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"http://farm%@.staticflickr.com/%@/%@_%@.jpg",flickrfarmID,flickrServer, flickrID,flickrSecret];
            NSString *stringURLSmallImage = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"http://farm%@.staticflickr.com/%@/%@_%@_s.jpg",flickrfarmID,flickrServer, flickrID,flickrSecret];


            [self.images addObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:stringURLOriginalImage,stringURLSmallImage, nil]];

            NSLog(@"%@", self.images);


        }


    } failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON) {

        NSLog(@"Request Failed with Error: %@, %@", error, error.userInfo);

    }];
    [operation start];

}
```

Comment: What method is that?  What's the idea with storing an array of arrays (with the inner array having 2 members)?

Comment: I'm using KTPhotoBrowser and that is the way they use it to load images. One image is for the thumbnail and one image is for the large image.

Answer (score 0):

Change :

```
self.images = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects: [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"http://farm6.staticflickr.com/5095/5426345292_40ec29d5ea.jpg", @"http://farm6.staticflickr.com/5095/5426345292_40ec29d5ea_s.jpg", nil], nil];
```

To :

```
[self.images addObject:@"http://farm6.staticflickr.com/5095/5426345292_40ec29d5ea.jpg"];
[self.images addObject:@"http://farm6.staticflickr.com/5095/5426345292_40ec29d5ea_s.jpg"];
```

Comment: How do you know that's what the OP wants?

Comment: @trojanfoe from "MutableArray not storing information permanently" this. He is using the array twice first NSLog is working and when he is trying it in second it's not working.

Comment: Well it looks to me like he wants to store the images in pairs, hence the use of the inner array (one with the big image and another with the small image).